# Amature slowing down after separating and recombining in a single Armature multiple times

Tags: rigging

I’ve been having this problem recently where I’m working on an Armature where I would separate a Bone and later recombine it to make the rigging easier.

This is actually the second time that this has happend where in the first my personal speculation is that a Rigify created Armature adds additional data and duplicates some of it as Armatures gets separated and recombined which bogs down the system (scrolling through the Armature’s Object Data is also slow) prompting me to avoid it in the future.

Now that I’m in a similar situation where I’ve gotten really far with my rig so I don’t want to start from scratch again where the rig may have been from a Rigify created Armature which I don’t remember as it was one of the rigs I’ve worked on before and salvaged some of its Bones to improve upon.

I was wondering if there’s a way to purge whatever it is that’s slowing my armature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out.

It really was a Rigify issue. What happens is that it left out some junk Drivers and during the process of separating and recombining, it duplicated until there was too many and it slowed down the Armature.

The fix was to look at the drivers and well… delete them. It kinda took some time for me because simply clicking and showing the driver graph slowed Blender also.